# Chatter to Apex: Getting Attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, javascript-remoting, visualforce-template, chatter-api

I am using rest api (ConnectApi namespace output classes) to get the chatter feed details of a particular group in my org and using Javascript remoting to display the elements in a custom vf page. So far successful except the for the part of getting attachments or the files that was posted in the group. I am using the method getFeedElementsFromFeed(communityId, feedType, subjectId).

How can I get the files/attachments for each posts from the capability container (and also display them in the handlebar moustache template if possible) ?